# FormAssembly Using JavaScript to fill in fields based on an Event Select change

Tags: javascript, form

can't seem to get the select change to update the location field based on the repeater location section. No errors it simply does not change the location(tfa_4) drop-down to equal the repeater Location (tfa_1025)

```
        //I have a repeater Fieldset Section tfa_1025 where fields like Event Name, Location are displayed

        //with all the campaigns the logged in owner owns

        // When the selected event is changed.

          dropdownCampaign.addEventListener(

             'change',

             function() { 

                 var dropdownIndex = dropdownCampaign.selectedIndex; // Index of the currently selected event

                 console.log("Current event info:\nEvent Name: " + eventNames[dropdownIndex-1]+"\nLocation: " + eventLocations[dropdownIndex-1] + "\nStatus: " + eventStatus[dropdownIndex-1] + "\nType: " + eventTypes[dropdownIndex-1] + "\nStart Date: " + eventStartDates[dropdownIndex-1] + "\nEnd Date: " + eventEndDates[dropdownIndex-1]+ "\nStart Time: " + eventStartTimes[dropdownIndex-1] + "\nEnd Time: " + eventEndTimes[dropdownIndex-1]);

                 // Logic to prefill the event name using the currently selected event field tfa_8

                 document.getElementById("tfa_8").value = eventNames[dropdownIndex-1];



                //



                // Logic to prefill the location dropdown (tfa_4) using the currently selected event

                //tfa_1025 is the Fieldset Section displaying campaign info from owner

                  if (eventLocations[dropdownIndex-1] == "Oshawa") { 

                      SelectElement("tfa_4", "tfa_1025");

                  } else if (eventLocations[dropdownIndex-1] == "Pickering") {

                      SelectElement("tfa_4", "tfa_1025");

                  } else if (eventLocations[dropdownIndex-1] == "Whitby") {

                      SelectElement("tfa_4", "tfa_1025");

                  } 

              },

             false
```

Comment: As is, I'm not entirely sure that this is on-topic for Salesforce. Can you please clarify how this relates to Salesforce?

Comment: Indirectly related as the mapped dropdown list records are coming from Salesforce. Regardless of where it's coming from I thought I could get some feedback on the Javascript syntax part of my issue.  Hoping that someone here knows a lot more about manipulating JavaScript dropdowns that I do.

Answer (score 0):

resolved with:

```
// When the selected event is changed
```

dropdownCampaign.addEventListener(

```
 'change',
```

function getSelectedValue(){
      var x = document.getElementById("tfa_43").selectedIndex;
      var y = document.getElementById("tfa_43").options;

//pulls the status with a matching index from the status array
var statusToFind = eventStatus[x];
var dd = document.getElementById('tfa_14');

for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
console.log("Current event info:\oPTIONlENGTH: " + dd); 
    if (dd.options[i].text === statusToFind) {

```
    dd.selectedIndex = i;
    break;
}
```

}
return;
}
  );